# Check if two groups are correlated with years with hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have the following problem, I have a dataset with several countries, and a columns with prices for each year. Something with the form of:

```
country_name 2018 2019 2020
USA          0.04 0.5  0.6
...
```

And another dataset with the same structure but different data.
I want to check if those two are correlated applying some sort of hypothesis testing.
The countries in the datasets are the same, and one has the price of the gas and the other the price of the electricity.
I would also need to check it using several methods, but I don't know which methods would be appropiated for this. I can also use regressions or so.
Also note that I have only 12 countries.

Comment: Note that, due to inflation, almost all prices will tend to go up over time, rendering "correlation" rather meaningless; the price of crude oil averaged around \$3.22 in 1972 and \$65.85 in 2021 (https://www.thebalance.com/oil-price-history-3306200) and the price of tin went from about \$3500/ton to about \$35000/ton over the same period (https://tradingeconomics.com/commodity/tin).  Meaningful?  I rather doubt it.

Comment: @jbowman one dataset has the price of the crude and the other the price of the electricity. I want to compare those

Comment: Over a long period of time, both prices will go up, because most prices go up, so they will be correlated.   A test won't really tell you anything you shouldn't know in advance.  Does a positive correlation mean anything other than that prices, in general, go up?  What are you actually trying to determine?

Comment: @jbowman the h0 is that the price of the gas is not related to the price of the electricity. It doesn't need to be accurated, it's just an exercise I want to do because it seems interesting due the fact that I have several countries and years, and I would like to understand how to approach this kind of problem.

Comment: @jbowman also I only have data from 4 years, from 2017 to 2021